# Table Widget in Symfony

Tags: symfony1

Is there a table widget for Symfony? I know there are people who [planned to build this](http://www.mail-archive.com/symfony-devs@googlegroups.com/msg02145.html), but don't know whether it got incorporated into Symfony or not.

It would be tremendously useful if table widget is available and all we have to do is to bind the `array` to it and it will show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like [this one](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDatagridPlugin) ?

Comment: Seems to me like this is the one